# How do i teleport (randevous) in KSP next to the target i want to be?

Tags: kerbal-space-program, cheats

I can't find a way to rendezvous cheat nearby my space station, I get I can just fly my craft, but its too out of control if I leave it on for too long. So can anybody tell me, how do I rendezvous CLOSER to my target?

Answer (score 3):

- Focus on your ship
- Press Alt+F12
- Goto Cheats => define orbit
- Bottom, cycle through all your ships/objects
- Click on rendez-vous

[image: Cheat image]

Note that the game will put you at 150m of the ship. You have to either EVA your kerbals or use RCS or your main engine to approach. If your ships are rotating out of control, timewarp quickly.

Comment: Note: Copying orbit data from one craft to the other in savegame file puts them at 0 distance, and in consequence they are either breaking each other, or "bounce away" unpredictably, sometimes with great speed. Thus, the 150m distance is actually desired.